# How to detach a terminal pane to a new window?

Tags: linux, terminal, terminator

Is it possible to detach one of the terminal panes (split windows, not tabs) in `terminator` and move it to a new window? I know there is a workaround (see the answers below) but I'm looking for a better (more user-friendly) solution.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a workaround:

1. Press `Ctrl + Shift + i` to open a new window. You need to open it like this, the workaround doesn't work if you start a new terminator process.
2. Then you can move terminal panes from one window to another using drag & drop so you can move the pane you want to detach to the new window.
3. Now you have two panes in the new window - one started with the window and one you moved there. Just close the original pane and you have only the pane you originally wanted to detach to a new window.

But I'm hoping for a better way.

Comment: This is a nice workaround to a feature that unfurtunately doesnt exist in terminator yet :( Maybe I should try hack around in the code and get this to work as intended

Comment: its not as ideal as dragging the window to where you want it, but at least it's possible. Thanks!

Comment: @SamMarinelli, what exactly did you do and what happened?

Comment: When I try to drag a pane from one window to the other, nothing happens.  Specifically I click the tab at the top of one window and then drag to the other window and release the mouse, but the other window does not respond.

Comment: @SamMarinelli, wait, are you talking about tab or pane (as in a split window)? This isn't meant for tabs but I just tried this again with panes and it works as expected.

Comment: Whoops, I see now.  I thought "pane" was just the parlance you were using for tabs.

Comment: Yeah, the terminology may be confusing. I will update the original question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [the correct solution mentioned by @geckon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35410240/878954), I found a workaround to get this workaround to work for tabs (as opposed to panes which is the main topic) by just creating an extra pane and apply @geckon solution.

Here are the steps:

- create a pane in the tab you want to move. Now you have two panes, one you want to move and the other is extra
- create a tab in the window you want to move to
- move the desired pane (not the tab) to the new window's tab, then exit the extra panes if you want.

I know, a bit of a "pane" in the neck! I hope they add it as a feature. Great product though!

Answer (score -1):

Create a new terminal tab, click on the 'tab' tab on the menu bar, select detach tab

Comment: Which terminator version do you use? Please note that the original question was about panes, not tabs.